# Finite dimensional vector space V over the rationals which is not a subset of the reals and which is not a field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

This was a bonus question on an old assignment, unfortunately, I cannot find the solutions. The question asks to find an example of a finite dimensional vector space V over the rationals, where V is NOT a subset of the reals, and V is NOT a field.
I'm not too sure how one would approach this problem, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Polynomials with degree $\leq n$ and rational coefficients should work I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $\mathbb{Q}^2$? It satisfies all of those conditions.

Comment: If I were to define multiplication like in the case of $R^2$, would it not give a subfield of the complex numbers?

Comment: No. The set $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R$.